# Programmatically Creating Controls in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, controls

According to *Cocoa Programming for Mac OS X, 3rd Edition*, on page 245 (chapter 17), you will usually create views in Interface Builder. However, it is possible to create them in code, a la:

```
NSView *superview = [window contentView]; 
NSRect frame = NSMakeRect(10, 10, 200, 100); 
NSButton *button = [[NSButton alloc] initWithFrame:frame]; 
[button setTitle:@"Click me!"]; 
[superview addSubview:button]; 
[button release];
```

That’s all well and good, but how would I wire up said control’s outlets to actions in code? (In .NET, this is an easy thing; add a delegate ... I’m hoping it’s similarly easy in Cocoa/Obj-C.)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can wire them up using a simple assignment. To continue your code from above:

```
[button setTarget: self];
[button setAction: @selector(myButtonWasHit:)];
```

Comment: Beautiful, thanks! That's actually easier than it is in .NET.

Answer (score 11):

And if you want to target the first responder rather than a particular object:

```
[button setTarget:nil];
[button setAction:@selector(myAction:)];
```

Answer (score 3):

Swift:

```
button.target = self
button.action = "myAction:"
```

And of course add myAction function to self:

```
func myAction(sender: NSButton) {
    println("click!")
}
```